# To indicate to which time "having been" is used?

Tags: infinitives, to-infinitive, perfect-infinitive

1. To have loved and lost is better than never to have loved at all.
2. Having loved and lost is better than never having loved at all.
3. Having been loved and lost is better than never having been loved at all.
4. Getting loved and lost is better than never getting loved at all.

The meanings of first two sentences are clear to me. The first example is hypothetical, and it is used to indicate past, present and future, while second example is used to indicate only past. Please say something about third and fourth examples. When can they be used?

Comment: Are you sure about the "to have loved"? What is the grammar? however, having loved is perfect participle and having been loved is the passive form of the perfect participle.

Comment: @Cardinal: "To have eaten a light breakfast is better than to have eaten no breakfast at all."   The words of a person whose stomach is (or is not) growling around 10:30AM.

Comment: The 4th one is not grammatical.  It should be "losing", not "lost" and "than" not "that" (though the latter error is probably just a typo).

Comment: @TRomano So, does it perfect infinitive?

Comment: @Cardinal [pretty sure, yeah.](http://mobile.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alfredlord153702.html)

Answer (score 1):

"been loved" means having received love from someone else, as opposed to you loving someone else, as in the first two sentences.

So the third sentence is awkward because "lost" should presumably also be attributed to the other person as well:

"Having been loved and been lost is better than never having been loved at all."

But the problem then is that means the other person lost you, rather than you 
losing them. Because if you wanted to go on being loved by them, you would let them find you. And if you didn't, never having been loved at all would probably be better.

In other words, never having been stalked is better than being stalked and losing the stalker.

Therefore, since "loved" in the first two sentence implies mutual love anyway, there really doesn't seem to be a reason to write the third sentence.

The fourth sentence is not idiomatic at. We say "getting lost" (a process) but "being loved" (a state).